# limit length of TTPostController.textView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have ttpostcontroller and i want to limit the length of the ttpostcontroller.textView.

i have this method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
return (newLength > 500) ? NO : YES;

}
```

and i tryed to connect TTPostController's textView.delegate to `self` but this isnt worked:

```
postController.textView.delegate = self;
```

how i can limit the length to 500 charters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `TTPostController` and then **Implement this delegate method in your custom class**